# importing file containing xlrd module into other python files

Tags: python, xlrd

I have been trying to import this test.py file into another python file but to no success.

```
import xlrd
import term
import perpetuity

loc = "C:PycharmProjects/Life annuities/tables.xlsx"   # this is the file location.
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)


def tables_advance_perpetuity():
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
    num = int(input('enter the age of the life:'))
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        x = sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
        if x == num:
            dx = sheet.cell_value(num - 1, 2)
            nx = sheet.cell_value(num - 1, 6)
            print(dx)
            print(nx)
            ann = nx / dx
            print(f'Annuity value is {ann}')
```

On trying to import the test.py file into this python file(interface.py), the program runs and exits without importing the test.py file. However, I have been able to successfully import the term.py and perpetuity.py file

```
import perpetuity
import term
import test


print('Annuity options are :')
print('\t 1. Term annuities')
print('\t 2. perpetuities')
print('\t 3. deferred annuities')
print('=' * 50)
option = int(input('pick one that you want to compute: '))
print('=' * 50)
if option == 1:
    toption = int(input('\t1. Payable in Advance:\n'
                    '\t2. Payable in Arrears:\n'
                    '\t3. Payable continously:\n'))
    print('=' * 50)
    if toption == 1:
        term.Term_advance()
    if toption == 2:
        term.Term_arrears()
    if toption == 3:
        term.Term_continously()
        basis = input('what is the calculation basis::\n'
                  '1.\t AM 92\n'
                  '2.\t ELT 15 MALES\n')
        if basis == 1:
           test.tables_advance_term()
        print('end')
```

Comment: Have you installed the `xlrd` module? What's the error log?

Comment: Yes xlrd module is installed . On trying to call any function  from the test .py file ,the program just exits

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't importing your `test.py` file because it's instead importing the in-built python `test` package. Note that a package takes precedence over a module of the same name.

As seen below, I am able to successfully import the `support` module from the native python `test` package.

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> from test import support
>>>
```

To resolve simply change your `test.py` filename to a name that doesn't conflict with a in-built python library/package.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html